# use of capture in lambda comparator

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda

I created a priority_queue with type of pair, which stores the indices at two vectors (nums1[], and nums2[]) respectively.

nums1 and nums2 have been sorted.

I want the priority_queue top to hold the pair p such that nums1[p.first] + nums2[p.second] is the **minimum** among others elements in this priority_queue.

I wrote the following code but the pq top gave me the pair p that **maximizes** nums1[] + nums2[]. I can not figure out why. Could someone give me a hint? I understand this problem can be solved using a pq of a user defined class/struct, but I am curious to see how lambda function can be used here. Thanks.

```
 priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, function<bool(const pair<int,int>&, const pair<int,int>&)>> pq([&](const pair<int,int>&a, const pair<int,int>&b){
    return nums1[a.first] + nums2[a.second] > nums1[b.first] + nums2[b.second];
});
```

---

**To give the complete background information:**

The problem I am solving is below:

You are given two integer arrays nums1 and nums2 sorted in ascending order and an integer k.
Define a pair (u,v) which consists of one element from the first array and one element from the second array.
Find the k pairs (u1,v1),(u2,v2) ...(uk,vk) with the smallest sums.

My code is:

```
vector<pair<int, int>> kSmallestPairs(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2, int k) {
    vector<pair<int, int>> ans;
    int m = nums1.size();
    if(m == 0) return ans;
    int n = nums2.size();
    if(n == 0) return ans;
    priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, function<bool(const pair<int,int>&, const pair<int,int>&)>> pq([&]](const pair<int,int>&a, const pair<int,int>&b){
        return nums1[a.first] + nums2[a.second] > nums1[b.first] + nums2[b.second];
    });
    pq.push({nums1[0], nums2[0]}); // THIS LINE SHOULD BE pq.push({0, 0});

    unordered_set<string> visited;
    visited.emplace("0,0");
    while(!pq.empty() && k-- > 0) {
        auto top = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        int index1 = top.first, index2 = top.second;
        ans.push_back({nums1[index1], nums2[index2]});
        if(index1 + 1 < m && !visited.count(to_string(index1 + 1) + "," + to_string(index2))) {
            visited.emplace(to_string(index1 + 1) + "," + to_string(index2));
            pq.push({index1 + 1, index2});
        }
        if(index2 + 1 < n && !visited.count(to_string(index1) + "," + to_string(index2 + 1))) {
            visited.emplace(to_string(index1) + "," + to_string(index2 + 1));
            pq.push({index1, index2 + 1});
        }
    }

    return ans;
}
```

input nums1 = {1,7,11}, nums2 = {2,4,6}, k = 3

My incorrect output is ans = {{7,6},{11,6}}

Comment: Check out [the documentation for the comparator parameter](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/). "The expression comp(a,b), where comp is an object of this type and a and b are elements in the container, shall return true if a is considered to go before b."

Comment: `pq.push({nums1[0], nums2[0]});` should be `pq.push({0, 0});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo with your type: `pq` should store indexes, not value, replace

```
pq.push({nums1[0], nums2[0]});
```

by

```
pq.push({0, 0});
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/QI8GGY)

Comment: Thank you very much. I should have noticed this by myself if I was a little more careful ...